# If $f$ is a continuous odd function. Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then there is a continuous even function $g$ such that $f(x) = xg(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I'm working backwards to see if I can find the $g$, however, when I take the derivative of $xg(x)$  I have $f'(x) = g(x) + xg(x)'$ at $0$, then it will always ends up with $0$. Then I have no idea how to continue. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way of looking at this. Note that $f(0)=0$ because $f(x)$ is odd.

Hint: so $\cfrac {f(x)}x=\cfrac {f(x)-f(0)}x$

Comment: here is my thought: $ g(x) = \cfrac {f(x)}x=\cfrac {f(x)-f(0)}x$. Thus $\lim\limits_{x \to0}\frac {f(x)-f(0)}x =f'(0)$ which is $f'(x)$ exists. Thus, $g(x)$ is well-defined at $0$, and it's continuous.  Is this enough to be a correct proof? or do I need add anything else?

Comment: @Hobbit6094 Depending what you have already proved, you might need to say a little more about why $g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Solving for $g$, we obtain:
$$
g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}
$$
Since $y = f(x)$ and $y = x$ are odd, we know that $g$ is even. But what happens at $x = 0$?  How should we define $g(0)$ in order to guarantee that $g$ is continuous at $0$? **Hint:** Use L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

First, nobody says that $g$ is differentiable anywhere, and also nobody says that $f$ is differentiable at $x\neq 0$.

Second, why don't you take $f(x) = xg(x)$ as a definition of $g$ for $x\neq 0$? Will this $g$ be continuous for $x\neq 0$? Next, you have to show that $g$ can be continuously extended to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $g = \frac{f}{x}$ is even and solves $f = xg$ no matter what $f$ is. Your task is to prove that *if* $f$ is differentiable at $0$, *then* $g$ is continuous.

Your approach fails because you presume that $g\prime$ exists. It may not.